# How to sum dataframe column sections up to a time values contained in another dataframe in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, conditional-statements

I have a first dataframe df1 that looks like this:

```
                    volume
timestamp
2021-01-04 04:00:00   20
2021-01-04 04:30:00   5
2021-01-04 05:00:00   15
2021-01-04 05:30:00   5
2021-01-04 06:00:00   10
2021-01-04 06:30:00   5
2021-01-04 07:00:00   25
2021-01-04 07:30:00   5
2021-01-04 08:00:00   15
2021-01-05 04:00:00   25
2021-01-05 04:30:00   5
2021-01-05 05:00:00   5
2021-01-05 05:30:00   15
2021-01-05 06:00:00   10
2021-01-05 06:30:00   5
2021-01-05 07:00:00   15
2021-01-05 07:30:00   10
2021-01-05 08:00:00   20
...                  ...
```

And a second one df2 that looks like this:

```
                        high
timestamp                          
2021-01-04 05:30:00     134.43
2021-01-05 06:30:00     130.30
...                        ...
```

I need the sum of volume sections in df1 based on the timestamp values in df2. Meaning the sum of volume on  2021-01-04 from 04:00:00 to 05:30:00, and the sum of volume on 2021-01-05 from 04:00:00 to 06:30:00, in order to get a dataframe of results like this:

```
            volume_up_to_high
date
2021-01-04      45
2021-01-05      65
...            ...
```

What would be the simplest way to do it with in Python with Pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.merge` with `groupby.agg`:

```
# If not already done so, make `timestamp` columns datetime object
df1["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["timestamp"])
df2["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["timestamp"])

# Make `date` columns each as a common point for merge
df1["date"] = df1["timestamp"].dt.date
df2["date"] = df2["timestamp"].dt.date

# merge then groupby
df = df1.merge(df2, on="date")
new_df = df[df["timestamp_x"].le(df["timestamp_y"])].groupby("date").agg(volume_up_to_high=("volume", sum))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
            volume_up_to_high
date                         
2021-01-04                 45
2021-01-05                 65
```

Comment: Thank you Chris! Works great by putting "volume_x" instead of "volume".                        Also should I worry about these warnings when I make columns datetime objects, and is there a way to code the column change so that it doesn't create future problems:         
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead